# Circles randomly positioned wrapping the fixed markers

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, maps

Situation:

I am doing a game using Google Maps API v3. I have multiple *fixed* markers on the map and I can put **centered**
circles wrapping them.

What I really need:

To put those circles *randomly positioned* wrapping the fixed markers. I mean one circle for each marker and each time
in a different position but *every time* it should wrap the marker.

Any ideas?

#### Update

> What do you mean by "wrapping the fixed marker"?

I mean that the marker will be in a fixed position (its position will be loaded from a geojson file). But the circle should be randomly positioned, since it embrace/wrap the marker ever.

> Does each circle contain one or more markers or is it one circle that contains them all?

Each circle contains only one marker.

> How big are the circles?

Size will be random too. So `radius` could be any value between `1000` and `50000`.

#### Relevant parts of the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
    <style>
        html,
        body,
        #map {
            height: 100%;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            overflow: hidden;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="map"></div>
    <script>
        var gMap

        var gCenter = {
            lat: -15.793987,
            lng: -47.882794
        }

        var gStyles = {
            fillColor: 'red',
            fillOpacity: 0,
            strokeOpacity: 0,
            strokeWeight: 1,
            zIndex: 100
        }

        function initMap() {
            gMap = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
                center: gCenter,
                zoom: 13.5,
                disableDoubleClickZoom: true,
                styles: gStyles
            })

            ... 
            
            bootstrap()
        }

        function bootstrap() {
            ...

            var someMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: gCenter,
                map: gMap,
                title: 'Some Point',
                visible: true
            })

            var circle = new google.maps.Circle({
                map: gMap,
                center: gCenter, // <-- How to calculte randomly center here based in my someMarker position?
                radius: 100000, 
                fillColor: 'red',
                fillOpacity: 1,
                strokeWeight: 1,
                strokeOpacity: .5,
                strokeColor: 'red'
            });

            ...
        }
    </script>
    <script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=XXXX_API_XXXX&callback=initMap">
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "wrapping the fixed marker"?  Does each circle contain one or more markers or is it one circle that contains them all? How big are the circles?   Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the issue.

Comment: @geocodezip, I updated the question. Thanks for your remarks and sorry about the lacking of information.

Comment: How do you choose the size for the circles?  Is it the same for all markers?  Sounds like you want to iterate through your markers creating a random size and center of a circle with that size that contains the marker, then verify that candidate circle to ensure it doesn't contain any other markers.  Can the circles overlap?

Comment: @geocodezip, yeah, they are the same size. But the function to calculate the new circle position could take in account the radius value, preferably, because this may change. --- Basically, I need a function that would receive my marker position, create a circle around (wrapping) that mark but i dont want the marker is ever in the center because, depending on the game level, the marker will be invisible and I will show only the circle. But, if the marker is ever in the center, will be easy for the player to find the hidden place even without seeing the marker.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I managed resolve my problem:

```
calculateRandomCenter(lat, lng, radius) {
    let random = Math.random()
    let a = random * 2 * Math.PI
    let r = radius * Math.sqrt(random) / 120000 // this value is approximate

    let nLat = r * Math.cos(a) + lat
    let nLng = r * Math.sin(a) + lng

    return {lat: nLat, lng: nLng}
}
```

That function will receive a central lat and lng points (in my case, the center of my circle, that is a fixed place) and a radius of the circle that we need to position.Then, the function will calculate a new random latLng object inside that radius and return that object which can be used to set the new center of the circle.

That way I can keep my circle always around my original point (original center) *but* ramdomly positioned each time.

Examples:
[image][image]